# Calculate age & age buckets from a date field in powerquery

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am trying to create an ageing report from data in Power Query. I'm able to do the following if I pull the data into an Excel table:

*Age Column* =(TODAY()-[@[Request Date]])

*Ageing buckets* =LOOKUP(J19372,{-60,2.1,5.1,7.1},{"0-2","2+","5+","7+"})

However every time I refresh the data in the table from the query, I then need to copy the formulas down. This is fine for me but I want it to be automatic for others that I send the file to.

Is there a way to do those calculations in PowerQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Except for retrieving today's date via Power Query, you need to refresh table. Check one solution for banding here at Ken Puls blog: http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/02/29/creating-a-banding-function-in-power-query/

Comment: You can get the current date using either `DateTimeZone.LocalNow()` or `DateTimeZone.UtcNow()`.

Comment: @AlejandroLopez-Lago-MSFT sure, but TODAY() value will be changed on every recalculation, and PQ functions only at query refresh. That's what I meant